# Reading/returning variable values to/from custom classes to/from username - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, class, variables, methods

I have a custom created class btnClass based on CommandButton class.

```
Public WithEvents ButtonEvent As MsForms.CommandButton

Private Sub ButtonEvent_Click()

End sub
```

I have a UserForm1 that have one ListBox, one Label, and hundreds of dynamically created CommandButtons. I assigned btnClass to Buttons. When clicked on buttons, I want the Click event has the following result:

- If number of buttons selected (selQty) less than the Label.Caption (totalQty), and this button hasn't been selected before, add value to listBox and change BackColor.
- if this button selected previously, change color and decrease number of buttons selected (selQty) by 1.

I tried creating Public variables, but cannot get the result I want. Is this doable?

P.S. when the UserForm1 is activated, it means no button selected; as I click button I change the color of the button and accept it as selected.

Comment: What do you mean by `number of buttons selected`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean when the UserForm1 is activated, it means no button selected; as I click button I change the color of the button and accept it as selected.

Comment: Always helps to show what you tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to do something like this

clsButtonClick:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ButtonEvent As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub ButtonEvent_Click()
    'pass the button to the procedure in the userform
    ButtonEvent.Parent.HandleClick ButtonEvent
End Sub
```

Userform code:

```
Option Explicit

Const CLR_SEL As Long = vbRed         'selected color
Const CLR_NOT_SEL As Long = vbGreen   'unselected color

Dim btnCol As Collection
Dim maxQty As Long   'max number selectable
Dim currQty As Long  'number currently selected

'perform some setup
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Const NUM_BUTTONS As Long = 10
    Dim i As Long, btn As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim o As clsButtonClick

    currQty = 0  'number selected
    maxQty = 5   'max selectable
    Set btnCol = New Collection
    'add some buttons
    For i = 1 To NUM_BUTTONS
        Set btn = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btn" & i, True)
        btn.BackColor = CLR_NOT_SEL
        btn.Height = 18
        btn.Left = 20
        btn.Top = 20 * i
        btn.Caption = "Button " & i
        Set o = New clsButtonClick
        Set o.ButtonEvent = btn
        btnCol.Add o
    Next i
End Sub

'handle a button click event (button is passed in)
Sub HandleClick(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    If btn.BackColor = CLR_SEL Then
        btn.BackColor = CLR_NOT_SEL
        currQty = currQty - 1
    Else
        If currQty = maxQty Then
            MsgBox "no more selections available"
        Else
            btn.BackColor = CLR_SEL
            currQty = currQty + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: seems like this is what I want to do. Would it also be possible to do within ButtonEvent_Click without calling ButtonEvent.Parent.HandleClick?

Comment: Sure just move the `HandleClick` code into the class' `ButtonEvent_Click` method.

Comment: What about the values of maxQty, selQty, and ListBox1 on UserForm1? How to pass those values in and out of ButtonEvent_Click?

Comment: And that was my problem))

Comment: You may be able to get this to work inside the class, but that would be a poor design.  The class has no business knowing intimate details about the userform.  Tim's idea is the better way to go.

Comment: I agree with Brian ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started.

Create a wrapper class which wraps each button and handles its click event. Then when the form loads, loop through the controls and wrap the buttons.

A module level collection is required to hold the references of wrapped buttons (wrapper classes).

The *ButtonWrapper* class:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objButton As MsForms.CommandButton

'Wrap button
Public Function WrapCommandButton(btn As MsForms.CommandButton) As ButtonWrapper
    Set objButton = btn
    Set WrapCommandButton = Me
End Function

'Button's event handler
Private Sub objButton_Click()
    MsgBox objButton.Caption & " was clicked."
End Sub

'Clean up
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set objButton = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code behind the Form:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_handlers As Collection

'Initialize
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set m_handlers = New Collection

    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CommandButton" Then
            With New ButtonWrapper
                m_handlers.Add .WrapCommandButton(ctl)
            End With
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

'Clean up
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Set m_handlers = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: Form]

[image]

Hope this helps.